# Pydoop Installation on CentOS 6

Tags: python, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to install Pydoop (https://crs4.github.io/pydoop/installation.html) on CentOS 6 (Hortonworks HDP physical cluster, 4 nodes). I have Python 3.4 and Python 2.6 installed on my master. When I install it using Python 3 it shows syntax error like below:

```
[root@abc]# python3 setup.py build
  File "setup.py", line 45
print 'using setuptools version', setuptools.__version__
                               ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

When I install it using Python 2 it shows following error

```
[root@abc]# python setup.py build
using setuptools version 35.0.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 65, in <module>
    import pydoop
  File "/root/pydoop/pydoop/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
   _HADOOP_INFO = _PATH_FINDER.find()  # fill the cache ASAP
  File "/root/pydoop/pydoop/hadoop_utils.py", line 624, in find
  info[a] = getattr(self, a)()
  File "/root/pydoop/pydoop/hadoop_utils.py", line 433, in hadoop_home
_hadoop_home_from_version_cmd() or
  File "/root/pydoop/pydoop/hadoop_utils.py", line 394, in          
_hadoop_home_from_version_cmd
output = sp.check_output([hadoop_exec, 'version'])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'
```

I don't want to upgrade default python from 2.6 to 2.7 as it may break yum which uses python2.6 and upgrading it may cause problems. Any suggestions please?

Comment: pydoop requires 2.7 but if don't want to mess with your current instalation, you can use Pyenv to create a separated isolated environment. 

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Answer (score 0):

You can install Python 2.7 and pip on CentOS 6 **without** breaking yum:

```
# yum update
# yum install centos-release-SCL epel-release
# yum install python27 python27-devel
# echo ". /opt/rh/python27/enable" >/etc/profile.d/python.sh
# source /etc/profile
# curl -o get-pip.py https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
# python get-pip.py
# python --version
Python 2.7.13
# pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```